# Can't change colour of dots in gnuplot for many data columns

Tags: gnuplot

This is part of my data

```
845000 0 0 0 0 0 0
845001 0 0 0 8 0 0
845002 1 0 0 0 0 0
845003 0 0 0 0 0 0
845004 0 0 7 0 0 0
845005 0 0 0 0 0 0
845006 0 0 0 0 0 0
845007 0 2 0 0 0 0
845008 0 0 0 0 0 11
845009 0 0 0 0 0 0
845010 0 0 7 0 0 0
845011 0 0 0 0 9 0
845012 0 0 0 0 0 0
845013 0 0 0 0 0 0
845014 0 0 0 8 0 0
845015 0 0 0 8 0 0
```

This is my picture
[image: This is my picture]

So I want to have all dots in black colour, but I can't and I don't know why. I write "pointcolor "black" and it doesn't work.

I use this in gnuplot

```
plot for [col=2:7] 'polaczone.txt' using 1:col with points pointtype 7 pointcolor "black" pointsize 2
```

I also have a question is it possible to delete showing "0" dots? I don't want them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "linecolor" instead of "pointcolor".

Comment: Oh thanks it works. And do you know how can deal with "0"? I don't want them

Comment: Ask a new question to ask a new question :-)

Comment: Ok, I ask here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67753246/how-to-delete-all-zero-dots-in-gnuplot