# How to delete all zero dots in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

This is part of my data

```
845000 0 0 0 0 0 0
845001 0 0 0 8 0 0
845002 1 0 0 0 0 0
845003 0 0 0 0 0 0
845004 0 0 7 0 0 0
845005 0 0 0 0 0 0
845006 0 0 0 0 0 0
845007 0 2 0 0 0 0
845008 0 0 0 0 0 11
845009 0 0 0 0 0 0
845010 0 0 7 0 0 0
845011 0 0 0 0 9 0
845012 0 0 0 0 0 0
845013 0 0 0 0 0 0
845014 0 0 0 8 0 0
845015 0 0 0 8 0 0
```

This is my picture
[image]

So I want to delete all dots which == 0

Is it possible?

This is my plot line

```
plot for [col=2:7] 'polaczone845.txt' using 1:col with points pointtype 7 pointsize 1 linecolor "black"
```

Comment: You should also include your `plot` line.

Comment: You're right, so sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(1/0)` as an undefined value that will be skipped. So, use the following `using` expression:

```
1:((column(col) == 0 ) ? (1/0) : column(col) )
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to include into my plot line/